# Express router conflicting with Backbone pushstate

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

An Express `/` route serves my Backbone's app `index.html`.

I'm using `pushstate` in Backbone but the routes that Backbone should handled are being handled by express, giving `404` responses.

How can I setup Express to serve the `index.html` but to delegate other routes to Backbone?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the solution used by Backbone boilerplate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328513/backbone-js-and-pushstate

Comment: @WiredPrairie That only works when clicking anchors

Comment: You still need to do server side routes if a client is visiting that route directly.  Even if it's just serving up index.html; the server has to know what to do with it.

Comment: In a non-nodejs app, I just rewrote the URLs to include the #route in the other case. So, when it wasn't some special routes (like for REST API calls), a URL like /orders/123 became rootpage.html#orders/123 (Sorry, forgot to add that detail the 1st time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation you have multiple options:

1. You can have a server that handles the same routes as the client does and returns the same results. It is hard to implement but it gives a good url. Github did this.
2. Always return index.html and handle the route client side. (That is somewhat ugly and hard to maintain)
3. Don't use pushstate. Amen.

Comment: Using node/express, how can I accomplish the second option, routing all requests back to index.html?

Comment: You can use regexp in your routes. So lets say that you want to send index.html for all get request you could use: app.get("/*", function(){...)}). I personnally don't like this method since you can't have any other get request, but you could have a better regexp and omit some routes.

Comment: Or you could just use res.format - serve the json requests as you've been doing, but res.redirect the html requests back to the root http://stackoverflow.com/a/8928993/1094784

Answer (score 1):

You can use /* approach. Just have it as the last route. That way the other routes such as any service API calls will be matched before the catch all route of /* is matched. This is also how Backbone handles its routes.